# Spring Flux force to send data one by one instead of chunks

Tags: jquery, spring-webflux

I have the following Flux controller which returns "Name" objects as CompletableFutures are completed.

```
@GetMapping(value = "generate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Name> generate(@RequestParam String keywords) { 
    List<CompletableFuture<Name>> completableFuturesList = nameGeneratorService.generateNames(keywords, 1, 20);
    List<Mono<Name>> mono = completableFuturesList.stream().map(Mono::fromFuture).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return Flux.fromIterable(mono).flatMap(Function.identity());
}
```

The data is retrieved using JQuery using the code below

```
var last_response_len = false;
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/generate', type: 'get', data: { keywords: searchContent },
  xhrFields: {
    onprogress: function (e) {
      var this_response, response = e.currentTarget.response;
      if (last_response_len === false) {
        this_response = response;
        last_response_len = response.length;
      }
      else {
        this_response = response.substring(last_response_len);
        last_response_len = response.length;
      }
      console.log(typeof this_response);
      console.log(this_response);
      data = JSON.parse(this_response);
    }
  },
  success: function (data, status) {


  }
});
```

The problem I am facing is that it looks like Spring is not sending these line by line but by chunks if a series of CompletableFutures are completed about the same time.

Below are the console.log output from the browser

```
NEW RESPONSE!
{"name":"pizza","available":false}
NEW RESPONSE!
{"name":"pizzapie","available":true}
{"name":"sausagepizza","available":true}
{"name":"anchovypizza","available":true}
{"name":"pepperonipizza","available":true}
{"name":"cheesepizza","available":true}
{"name":"sicilianpizza","available":true}
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 43
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onprogress (script.js:65:27)
```

In the output above, we can see that there are many `Name` objects after the second "NEW RESPONSE!". If they were sent one by one, we should see "NEW RESPONSE!" after each Name object. This is causing issues with `JSON.parse` causing the `Uncaught SyntaxError`

Any idea what is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: I found a solution which is not ideal. Adding `delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(100));` to the Flux return statement